# Google Calendar API - Continuous syncing

Tags: google-calendar-api

I know how to sync with Google Calendar API. We are trying to build a system where to sync the Google Calendar continuously without asking for the consent screen.
I did search a lot but it seems they sent nextsynctoken to get the full event list. but If I want to restart the sync after 2 weeks. how can I do it? without asking auth window or consent screen to the user?

Please let me know if its possible.

Thank you in advance
Saravana

Comment: Unless you saved the refresh token from the user then your not going to be able to you need an access token inorder to request access

Answer (score 0):

All requests you are making to the Google Calendar API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

But since you are encountering a problem that looks like token expiration to me, why don't you try and refresh the **access tokens** you are using?

According to the [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) documentation

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

The `nextSyncToken` is a piece of data exchanged between the server and the client, and is used in the synchronization process.

You can keep on using the `nextSyncToken` but you will have to use a **refresh token** in order for you to not use the consent screen every time.

Here is a sample code from the [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) used to exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens, using Python:

```py
state = flask.session['state']
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'],
    state=state)
flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

authorization_response = flask.request.url
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

# Store the credentials in the session.
# ACTION ITEM for developers:
#     Store user's access and refresh tokens in your data store if
#     incorporating this code into your real app.
credentials = flow.credentials
flask.session['credentials'] = {
    'token': credentials.token,
    'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token,
    'token_uri': credentials.token_uri,
    'client_id': credentials.client_id,
    'client_secret': credentials.client_secret,
    'scopes': credentials.scopes}
```

I suggest you check the following links since they can provide more information on your issue:

1. [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)
2. [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)
3. [Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/sync)

For other programming languages used for the refresh token, you can check this:

4. [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: For a more customized response, I suggest you to provide more information, such as: the state of your application, what type of account and what programming language/technology are you using. Cheers!